# Access variable from view in module in joomla

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I created component for joomla according to mvc structure .I have some variable in my view and want to save that variable into database by model.My file structure:

```
-models
--contact.php
-views
--contact
---tmpl
----default.php
----default_comajax.php
---view.ajax.php
---view.html.php
```

My variable is in view.ajax.php and I want to save this variable within contact.php.
My view.ajax.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');
class contactfViewcontactf extends JViewLegacy
{
        function display($tpl = null) 
        {

    $name = "test";
    $this->get('Msg');

                parent::display(comajax);
        }
}
```

and my contact.php is

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
jimport('joomla.application.component.modelitem');
class contactfModelcontactf extends JModelItem
{
        public function getMsg() 
        {

    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "INSERT INTO #__rtuyds (email) VALUES ('$name')";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();
        }
}
```

How can I get access $name in contact.php?
the DB query executes and insert a new row in table but new row is empty and $name is not saved.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what version of Joomla are you using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want you need to do the following:

Modify your **model** like this using Lodder's query and adding an input to the getMsg() method:

```
public function getMsg($nameValue) 
{

   $db = JFactory::getDbo();

   $query = $db->getQuery(true);
   $query->insert($db->quoteName('#__rtuyds'))
      ->columns($db->quoteName('email'))
      ->values($db->quote($nameValue));
   $db->setQuery($query);
   $db->query();
}
```

Then inside your **view's** display method do the following:

```
function display($tpl = null) 
{

  $name = "test";
  $model = $this->getModel();
  $model->getMsg($name);

  parent::display(comajax);
}
```

Comment: thank you.my problem solved.but I have a question.If I want to call another model except from default model how to call it?

Comment: @adib16 here's how: [Using multiple models in an MVC component](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_multiple_models_in_an_MVC_component)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following as the update query:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__rtuyds'))
      ->columns($db->quoteName('email'))
      ->values($db->quote($name));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

Comment: problem is not query.

Comment: for example when i replace $name by a string that string save to data base.

Comment: @adib16 You can't store the `$name` that's why @Lodder suggests trying the above query instead.

Comment: i can not store $name because $name is defined in another file.I use require_once in contact.php to add view.ajax.php .but still not working.